# Flex - HTTPRequest to output html source in TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, httprequest

I have a TextArea and I'm trying to use HTTPRequest to fetch a website and output the html source 
in the TextArea but nothing is happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:ns1="*"
        actionBarVisible="true" currentState="landscape" tabBarVisible="false"
        overlayControls.landscape="false"
        tabBarVisible.landscape="false"
        actionBarVisible.portrait="true" viewActivate="view1_viewActivateHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="service" resultFormat="e4x"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextArea id="mainTextField" text="{service.lastResult}"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

            protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {
                service.url = "http://www.google.com";

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:actionContent>

    </s:actionContent>
    <s:titleContent>

    </s:titleContent>
    </s:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `service.send()` to send request.

Comment: BTW for anyone else having this problem I also had to change resultFormat="e4x" to resultFormat="text"